# How to change the state of one class from a function in a different class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a "edit" button that is created within a draggable-target class, which is basically an editable div box. When this button is clicked, it should change the state of the drawer class, making it "open", by calling the function handleDrawerOpen() in the drawer class. Any solutions as to how to effectively change the state of the drawer?

I've tried the method of making the drawer a constant object and calling the function of the object, but that isn't working for some reason.

This is the state and function for handleDrawerOpen/Close in the temporary drawer class, as well as how I'm exporting it to be used in other classes.

```
state = {
    open: false,
  };

  handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleDrawerClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

[rest of code here]

TemporaryDrawer.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const drawer = new TemporaryDrawer();
export default withStyles(styles)(TemporaryDrawer);
```

This is the edit button code in a different class. TemporaryDrawer is being imported into this class as well.

```
editButton() {
      console.log("working edit");
      alert('You can drag a different field or occupation from the drawer at the left!');
      drawer.handleDrawerOpen;
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors, but the drawer isn't opening when I click the edit button.

This is how I'm importing the temporarydrawer into the class where the button is called. I'm importing both the drawer object and the actual TemporaryDrawer class because the class itself needs to be displayed within the career-app class.

```
import drawer from './TemporaryDrawer.js';
import TemporaryDrawer from './TemporaryDrawer.js';
```

And this is how it's being rendered within the render function.

```
<div className="careerApp">
<TemporaryDrawer handleDrop={(target, type, name) => this.handleDrop(target, type, name)}/>
[There's a bunch of code here]
</div>
```

Comment: isn't it in react? also add react tag.

Comment: have you tried removing the class then adding it back? that's what I do

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar yes, sorry about that. I've added the tag.

Comment: @AndrewHansen like the whole entire drawer class?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `export default withStyles(styles)(drawer);`?

Comment: this looks like an import/export module issue. can you please add the code how you are importing `TemporaryDrawer` and how it is being used in `render` function ?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I also tried that, but I get the error message "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

Comment: @PranayTripathi sure!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `drawer.handleDrawerOpen()`:

```
editButton() {
    console.log("working edit");
    alert('You can drag a different field or occupation from the drawer at the left!');
    drawer.handleDrawerOpen();
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, and kept getting an error that said "WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__TemporaryDrawer_js.a.handleDrawerOpen is not a function" –

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the import are used twice and each import points to a specific instance. The problem is when you are calling `drawer.handleDrawerOpen()`, the component is not being used any where so that why you are getting WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE error. You cannot access the child function directly on the parent component. You will have to pass it as props handler to the `editButton`. Also have a look at the how you are structuring your components. This is not meant to be such complicated task. You can have a look at structuring you components in presentational and container structure. Have a look at the [link](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

If you can add the full components in codesandbox, we should be able to help you more.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is a prototype for a potential web app, so it's not really organized in the most conducive way, but I'll look into the presentational and container structure for the next iteration. I'm still a little confused about how to actually pass a props handler to the edit Button. Do you have an example? Also, I'll supply a link to my codepen, though I'm not sure how helpful it will be since you won't be able to actually see the components on the web page.

Comment: can you please share your codepen. I should be able to modify the code and give you a direction how can achieve the resolution to the problem.

Comment: its here: https://codepen.io/siran2020/pen/bZzZaL again i dont know how useful this is going to be because there are a lot of moving parts and you cant really run it on codepen but hopefully seeing the code helps.

Comment: https://codepen.io/pranaytripathi/pen/PLLJzr?editors=0010. I have isolated the state and manipulating it based on different behaviour out of the component. Normally you dont want to do that as it can be a bit difficult to manipulate. You are better off maintaining a component as a stateless component and let the stateful component decide the the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
editButton() { 
  console.log("working edit"); 
  alert('You can drag a different field or occupation from the drawer at the left!'); 
  drawer.handleDrawerOpen(); 
}
```